# Is almost sure convergence equivalent to pointwise convergence?

Tags: statistics, convergence-divergence, almost-everywhere, pointwise-convergence

I am getting confused with the difference between pointwise convergence and almost sure convergence (or if there should be any difference at all)...

Say that I have a random variable $X_n=n1_{[0,1/n]}$. In this case, $X_n$ converges to $0$ pointwise, and it also converges in probability, since:

$$
P(|X_n - 0| > \epsilon) = \frac{1}{n} \rightarrow 0
$$

However, even though $X_n$ converges pointwise, this is not almost sure convergence right? Since we have

$$
\sum P(|X_n - 0| > \epsilon) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} = \infty
$$

since the sum diverges, it means (using the Borel-Cantelli lemma) that it is not convergence almost surely.

So how should I relate the following?

- convergence pointwise
- convergence almost surely
- convergence almost everywhere

Comment: Borel-Cantelli for divergent series of probabilities has an assumption in it. Do you remember which one? And yes a.e. pointwise convergence is the same as convergence a.e..  You use a.s. instead of a.e. if you deal with probability spaces but you can also just say a.e. even in that case as others do the same.

Comment: I think you intended to have the uniform measure on the space $[0,1]$? Then you see that for every $\omega\in (0,1]$ for $n$ large enough we have $X_n(\omega)=0$. Since $\mathbb P((0,1])=1$ you have a.s. convergence to $0$.

Comment: From the text am reading, it states that the Borel Cantelli lemma says that if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(A_n)<\infty$ then $P(\text{lim sup}A_n)=0$. So am interpreting it that if $A_n = |X_n-0|$, we have that $X_n$ converges to $0$ almost surely. But in this case, $A_n$ diverges... what's the assumption am lacking?

Comment: Yes, it's the uniform measure...

Comment: If you want to use that $\sum_n \mathbb P(A_n)=\infty$ implies that $\mathbb P(A_n \text{ i.o.} )=1$ then you need the $A_n$s to be independent events. Do you have that here?

Comment: Oh right ! I didn't see that independence assumption. That's cool. Thanks. You should have written this as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the comments it is clear that the probability space is $\Omega=[0,1]$ endowed with the Borel-$\sigma$-algebra and the uniform measure, call it $\mathbb P$.

Let's clarify the definitions first. *Almost everywhere convergence* is the same as saying that there exists some $\Omega^*$ for which $\mathbb P(\Omega^*)=1$ and $X_n$ converges pointwise on $\Omega^*$. That is for all $\omega\in\Omega^*$ we have $X_n(\omega)\to X$ for some random variable $X$. In probability setting one usually uses "almost surely" instead of "almost everywhere". One also says converges *surely* if $\Omega^*=\Omega$, i.e. the whole space.

Using this definition we see that for all $\omega \in (0,1]:=\Omega^*$ we have $X_n(\omega)=0$ for $n$ large enough. Moreover $\mathbb P((0,1])=1$ which means that we have almost surely convergence to $0$.

Where does the application of Borel-Cantelli goes wrong in the question then? Well, for the use of Borel-Cantelli like that one needs to assume that the events are independent. However they are not. Just see that for $\varepsilon\in (0,1)$ the event $\{|X_n-0|\leq \varepsilon\}$ implies that $\{|X_m-0|\leq \varepsilon\}$  for all $m>n$ (You see this?).